# Fabric.js "reverse" and "layered" clipping/cropping

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, fabricjs, crop

In the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22260287/fabric-js-clipping-individual-objects-dynamically), [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86bTc/4/) does the "normal" cropping, i.e. the image outside the grayed-area rectangle will be cropped, and only the image inside the gray rectangle area will remain.

The key codes of "normal" cropping use the function "clipTo":

```
object.clipTo = function (ctx) {
    ctx.rect(
        -(eWidth / 2) + left, 
        -(eHeight / 2) + top, 
        parseInt(width * eScaleX), 
        parseInt(eScaleY * height)
    );
}
```

What I want to achieve is doing a "`reverse`" cropping, i.e. the image inside the gray rectangle will be cropped, and only the image outside the gray rectangle area will remain.

This is the first part. The second part is to do "`layered`" cropping, i.e. the object with lower `z-index` value (`object A`) will be cropped by the object (`object B`) which has higher `z-index` value and overlaps the `object` A. The overlapped area of the object A will be cropped.

Is this doable? I spent much time but couldn't find the solution nor achieve this on my own.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use an inverted clip path group as this example shows

```
      let clip_rect = new fabric.Rect({ left: 220, top: 150, width: 70, height: 50 });
      let g = new fabric.Group([clip_rect]);
      g.inverted = true
      g.absolutePositioned = true

      object.clipTo = g
```